# Why are my button images blurry on mobile screens?

Tags: images, buttons

I have a few custom buttons I've inserted with php throughout my wordpress site. They are crisp resolution images (either gif or png), but when viewing it on my iphone screen, they're blurry. I noticed the other plugins I have installed that insert the same type of .png images buttons look very sharp when viewed on a mobile screen, or any screen for that matter.

What am I missing? Can't figure out why a png inserted button from a wordpress plugin looks crisp on all screens, but my png buttons only look good on desktop screens.

Answer (score 0):

Because Apple devices have something called retina screen. Where pixel density is double then "normal" screen. You will have to add image that is double the size. You can do this manually or use some plugins like wp retina.